# What is the difference between clearcase and vss in label a release?

Tags: visual-sourcesafe, clearcase

We are using clearcase as our SCM. I have not much experience with clearcase. Now we are about to release our code to production. I want to label my code as I have done using VSS in my previous projects. But in clearcase labeling is not as easy as in VSS. clearcase is asking to create a label type before label a folder in VOB. I don't understand the concept of creating label type? Any guidance on this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know anybody used either of those anymore.  I'm really sorry to hear that...

Comment: I'm using ClearCase right now...

Comment: I just completed my question to answer your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- a lbtype is a template, a declaration.
- a label is the instance that will be put on each versions needed to be labeled.

See [`mklbtype`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklbtype.htm)

> The `mklbtype` command creates one or more **label types with the specified names for future use within a VOB**.
>   After creating a label type in a VOB, you can attach labels of that type to versions of that VOB's elements, using `mklabel`.

You also can attach a constraint on a `lbtype`:

> By default, a new label type is constrained to **use on only one version in an element's entire version tree**.
>   This allows you to omit the branch path name portion of a version-extended path name (for example, `foo.c@@/JOHN_TMP`)

---

Once you have define a `lbtype`, you can apply (**[`mklabel`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mklabel.htm)**) it to any file or group of files you want in your current view.
That means you have a view configured to select the `LATEST` of a branch, and at a given time, you apply this label:

```
cd /myView/myVob/myGroupOfFile
cleartool mklabel -nc -r MY_LABEL-1.0 .
```

Note: the name of the `lbtype` (and the labels set from this `lbtype`) is entirely up to you. You can set a label `FOO`, `BAR` or any other names. Conversely, you can set a label `MY_LABEL-2.0`, *then* set a label `MY_LABEL-1.2` (not wise, but...).

If you want to see what exact versions are referenced by a previous existing label like `MY_LABEL-1.0`, you create *another (dynamic) view* that you set to see this label.
The following config spec ("configuration specifications", aka "selection rules" for versions) will achieve just that:

```
element * MY_LABEL-1.0
element * /main/LATEST
```

The second selection rule is called "stop rule" because it allows for all versions to "fall back" to this default rule: if no version (for a given file) is labeled `MY_LABEL-1.0`, *then* it will *always* stop at the "`/main/LATEST`" rule, to select the `LATEST` version of the branch `main`.

For those "consultation" view (i.e. "view that are only used to see versions of files"), I recommend dynamic view, for a quick access to those fixed versions.
If you now want to see the 2.0 label, simply modify the config spec of this view. Or create another view, in order to see both 1.0 (in the first view) and 2.0 (in this second new view)

Comment: Hi VonC,
Thanks a lot.In VSS label is just text to identify a set of files with their versions at a particular point in time. In VSS before I release version 1.0 I label my code as "VERSION1.0" and any feature to this release, I lable my code as "VERSION1.1" and after that If want to get "VERSION1.0" code I just go to history and get the code with "VERSION1.0" label. I want to do the same in clearcase for project in our team's VOB. Can u let me know how to do that.