# Copy Labelled Nodes in Same VOB from one branch to another in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I am having 2 branches: Branch-1: Stable Branch, Branch-2: Develpoment Branch.

There are several checked-in nodes in Branch-2. Out of them, around 3 nodes have labels: L1, L2 & L3:

> ```
> x  [Branch-1: Stable Branch (only one node)]
> ```

```
   \ 
    x - x - x (L1) - x - x(L2) - x (L3) - x - x 

[Branch-2: Dev Branch (several checked-in
 nodes), 3 nodes labelled with: L1, L2, L3 => I want to copy these 3 nodes 
 to Branch-1]
```

Can you please provide a clearcase command to do this?

Thanks.

Best Regards,

Sandeep Singh

Answer (score 0):

First you need a [dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view/2925378#2925378):

- it is quicker in order to avoid all the updates involved with a snapshot view
- you can actually copy an extended path names, meaning you can [copy a version which is not visible in your dynamic view, through its extended pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987427/why-cant-perl-find-my-file-that-is-in-clearcase/988904#988904).

So you define a dynamic view for updating `Branch1` (ie with a selection rule ending with `-mkbranch Branch1`: see "[How to create a branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580597/how-to-create-a-branch/6581282#6581282)" for the three selection rules you need).

Then you need to find each relevant versions for `L1` and copy them on top of your current view, putting a different label on that new version in `Branch1` ([create a `L1B1` lbtype first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277527/what-is-the-difference-between-clearcase-and-vss-in-label-a-release/1277549#1277549), for instance):
Windows syntax:

```
 cleartool find . -ver "lbtype(LBL1)" \
 -exec "cleartool co -c \"LBL1 import\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\" ; \
        cp \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\" ; \
        cleartool ci -nc \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\" ; \
        cleartool mklabel –replace L1B1 \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""
```

(in one line: `cleartool find . -ver "lbtype(LBL1)" -exec "cleartool co -c \"LBL1 import\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\" ; cp \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\" \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\" ; cleartool ci -nc \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\" ; cleartool mklabel –replace L1B1 \"%CLEARCASE_PN%\""`)

Unix syntax:

```
 cleartool find . -ver "lbtype(LBL1)" \
 -exec "cleartool co -c \"LBL1 import\" \"$CLEARCASE_PN\" ; \
        cp \"$CLEARCASE_XPN\" \"$CLEARCASE_PN\" ; \
        cleartool ci -nc \"$CLEARCASE_PN\"; \ 
        cleartool mklabel –replace L1B1 \"$CLEARCASE_PN\""
```

(one line: `cleartool find . -ver "lbtype(LBL1)" -exec "cleartool co -c \"LBL1 import\" \"$CLEARCASE_PN\" ; cp \"$CLEARCASE_XPN\" \"$CLEARCASE_PN\" ; cleartool ci -nc \"$CLEARCASE_PN\"; cleartool mklabel –replace L1B1 \"$CLEARCASE_PN\""`)

`CLEARCASE_XPN` reference the full extended pathname, accessible from a dynamic view,  `CLEARCASE_PN` references the path without the extended path, ie without the part after the `@@`.
There are environment variables set by the `cleartool find` command, hence the `%...%` or `$` used.

Repeat that for `L2` and `L3`, and you will get, for a given file:

```
x - y (L1B1) - y (L2B1) - y (L3B1)  [Branch-1: Stable Branch (only one node)]
 \ 
  x - x - x (L1) - x - x(L2) - x (L3) - x - x
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But if I am having a large code-base, is there any way of doing the same with the help of Labels only, rather than working on individual files?

Comment: @SandeepSingh: please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645008/what-are-the-basic-clearcase-concepts-every-developer-should-know/645771#645771: ClearCase always works file-by-file. But the `cleartool find` is there to help you apply a sequence of commands for each version found with a specific label. So you need to repeat the `cleartool find` command I mention only for each label name, not for each file. It will checkout, copy, checkin and apply a new label (`L1B1`) for each file found with a version already labelled `L1`. So in that respect, you will work with the help of labels.

Comment: @SandeepSingh: so did you manage to make it work? Don't forget you can first test it with a more simpler find command: `cleartool find . -ver "lbtype(LBL1)" -exec "echo \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%, %CLEARCASE_PN%\""` in order to display the version to copy, and the file to overwrite. Then you can try the more complete and complexe sequence of commands within the "`exec`" directive.

Comment: Happy New Year & Thanks a lot for your help. This time, I was not able to make it. Faced issues even after giving absolute paths for file names. I resolved the issue through merging & then automatic labeling (through a script - for intermediate nodes). Actually, I was working on a development branch. We placed 3 major labels on the code. Now, the last job was to bring the labeled nodes on the destined parent branch. I will certainly give this method a better try so that I don't face this problem in future.