# mkbl on prior delivery not progressing

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Running CC 8.0.0.3 w/UCM and ClearQuest enabled.

We have a build system which is supposed to run mkbl -view after a successful build in the integration stream. Normally this completes in a few seconds after each build. That works fine, but it turns out one build job omitted the mkbl command.

I am trying to retroactively apply the mkbl command for those. I need to do this 4x  to come up to date.

BL label -  #activities - # element versions

- 1.2.6   -   57   -  513
- 1.2.7   -   16   -  107
- 1.3.0   -   26   -  159
- 1.4.0   -   60   -  460

I have attempted the command:

```
cleartool mkbl -view my_view  -act ${ACT_LIST} -inc  -c "${LABEL}" ${LABEL}
```

where ACT_LIST is the list of activities (activity@/mypvob), since the prior baseline, LABEL is my label

It's been running over 12 hours and still has not even come back indicating creating baseline.

Am I doing this wrong? Is it just slow? Is it possible to retroactively apply a baseline?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it would be quicker for your first non-missing baseline is [promoted to "full" instead of incremental](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9696988/6309): the delta (of files or activities) between two baselines would be quicker to compute.

You can keep creating incremental baselines on top of that full one.

Then you can start testing making a baseline with just one activity and see if that complete: making multiple baselines with the same label will lead to [multiple baselines with different ID (same title)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10233934/6309).

> Is it possible to retroactively apply a baseline?

Baselines are created sequentially on the stream: they cannot be "inserted".
If you already started to put new baselines on that stream (after missing a couple), you cannot try and create ones before.

But the OP mentions:

> No, there were no subsequent baselines and the first baseline's list of activities goes back to the last actual baseline.

---

Since `mkbl` fails (too long), I would:

- change the config spec of the UCM view in order to select files before a certain date (add a **[time-based selection rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/635282/6309)** at the start of its config spec)
- put a label on *all* files of the component ([`mklbtype`+`mklabel`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1277549/6309))
- import that non-UCM label as a baseline ([`mkbl -import`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mkbl.htm))

See if you can create your baselines that way.

---

The [OP Ian W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/598141/ian-w) concludes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441531/mkbl-on-prior-delivery-not-progressing/24444622#comment38682975_24444622):

> neither incremental nor full worked.
>
> I tried `mkbl -import`, but then I could not recommend and use as a future baseline, so I gave up.
>
> I had the 4 baseline equivalents all labelled, then made a full of the latest, which worked and should keep me moving forward

Comment: No, there were no subsequent baselines and the first baseline's list of activities goes back to the last actual baseline. By retroactive, I really mean make the baselines (w/today's timestamp) corresponding to the delivered changes which went into the build x.y.z, as they should have been created. After 20+ hrs, I Ctrl-C'd and tried a -full, which is now 8 hrs in; similar lack of progress.

Comment: @IanW Ok, I have edited the answer to propose an alternative way to create your baseline (component by component)

Comment: Well, neither incremental nor full worked. I tried mkbl -import but then I could not recommend and use as a future baseline, so I gave up. I had the 4 baseline equivalents all labelled, then made a full of the latest, which worked and should keep me moving forward.

Comment: @IanW Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility, for you to select.